# What is difference between a service Layer and Business Layer in N layered architecture

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, architecture

What is difference between a service Layer and Business Layer in N layered architecture

I am building N layered application, so I have gone through many resources on N layered architectures which contain layers such as a service layer 
egs https://prodinner.codeplex.com/

a service class in the above project

```
public class UserService : CrudService<User>, IUserService
{
    private readonly IHasher hasher;

    public UserService(IRepo<User> repo, IHasher hasher)
        : base(repo)
    {
        this.hasher = hasher;
        hasher.SaltSize = 10;
    }

    public override int Create(User user)
    {
        user.Password = hasher.Encrypt(user.Password);
        return base.Create(user);
    }

    public bool IsUnique(string login)
    {
        return !repo.Where(o => o.Login == login, true).Any();
    }
}
```

So is the traditional business layer same as service layer ?

Comment: Usually the service layer handles CRUD operations and the business layer is where the business rules and logic are applied.

Answer (score 1):

The basic difference is Business Layer is to define business logic ( data transformation ) and Service Layer is to access data from different client's.
In our projects we often have the following structure:

Service layer:

Publishes the Service Endpoint (this could be your MVC web page, or a WCF endpoint)
Does a security check
Maps data from contract data transfer objects to business objects
Calls functionality in the business layer

Business layer

Contains business logic
Accesses the data layer (this could be your entity framework data model)